# targeting inner html of second element child of a table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to target the second child element of my table.  In this case, I would want to write the inner HTML of the second cell of the row, which is "Travolta." I've used the firstChildElement and lastChildElement with success, but having trouble targeting  the second one. Any help would be appreciated!  Example code can be found below:

HTML:

```
  <tr class="table-row">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Travolta</td>
      <td>j.travolta@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
```

Javascript:

```
var rowTag = document.getElementsByClassName("table-row");

document.write(rowTag[0].firstElementChild.innerHTML);
```

--> returns "John"

```
document.write(rowTag[0].lastElementChild.innerHTML);
```

--> returns "j.travolta@gmail.com"

Comment: I don't see how your first example would work at all when `["table-row"]` should be `("table-row")`

Comment: rowTag[0].cells[1].innerHTML;  Demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYzyZO

Comment: Try to assign an id to your second td or alternatively get the second cell as .cells[2].innerHTML.

Comment: You are correct @j08691, should have been parentheses, my mistake.  Will edit the comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's the *second* element child, perhaps use `children[1]` (it's a 0-based collection):

```
var text = rowTag[0].children[1].innerHTML;
```

Note that `firstElementChild` and `children` are supported on modern browsers, but if you have to support IE8, you're stuck with writing a function to skip past non-element nodes.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks TJ!     document.write(rowTag[0].children[1].innerhtml) returned "Travolta" as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `rowTag[0].firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.innerHTML`

Comment: `nextElementSibling`. The `nextSibling` could be a text node.

Comment: It's fine to edit the answer when minor points like that are noted. I didn't want to just jump in and do it, though in retrospect I'm not sure why not.

Comment: ...but not to edit it so it's the same as another answer already posted.

Answer (score 0):

Get innerHTML like this

```
var tr = document.getElementsByClassName('table-row');

alert(tr[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a CSS selector, nth-child().
Just put the child number inside the parenthesis.
Using JQuery, here's how this would solve your problem:
`$('tr.table-row>td:nth-child(2)')` is a straightforward selector to retrieve the required element using JQuery. To set its HTML is simply a matter of using the `html()` function like this:

`$("tr.table-row>td:nth-child(2)").html("SET HTML HERE");`

Comment: How is styling the element going to retrieve the content?

Comment: @j08691 `$('tr.table-row>td:nth-child(2)')` is a straightforward selector to retrieve the required element using JQuery. That it is a CSS selector does not mean styling is all it can be used for. To set its HTML is trivial after that. Simply use the `html()` function like this: `$('tr.table-row>td:nth-child(2)').html("SET HTML HERE");`.

Comment: Your answer, until you edited it, neither mentioned nor contained any jQuery. Furthermore this question isn't tagged with or about jQuery.

Comment: @j08691 Hopefully, my explanation helped you make sense of my answer.